# WP input box shows white background, even though I change to "background-color: none;" (Themify bulider)

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7, input-field

Could someone help me with an annoying error?

I want to change the form input fields to transparent background, keeping only the solid line under the field in Themify Bulider with Contact form 7. When I add the custom CSS shown bellow, it still keeps me with the white input boxes, as you can see from: www.creedo.ee.

```
.wpcf7 input[type=text]{
   border: none;
   box-shadow: none;
   border-radius: 0;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
   background-color: none;
}
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: can you please share a page link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
.mdc-text-field {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```